# KeyError: 'sessionId' when using IEWebDriver in Robot Tests

Tags: webdriver, robotframework, sessionid, keyerror

i am getting a KeyError: 'sessionId' error when im running my robot tests on Internet Explorer using IEWebDriver. i made sure i am using the latest IEWebDriver (which is 3.6). when i run in Chrome, everything is running fine. how do i fix this?

here are some system information:

- IE version: 11
- Robot Framework Version: 2.9
- robotframework-selenium2library version: 1.7.4
- windows version: 7

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't added the driver to your PATH

Comment: i already have this code:

set IEWebdriver
    set environment variable    webdriver.ie.driver     C:\Python27\IEDriverServer.exe

i also have C:\Python27 saved on my PATH variable in My Computer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but fixed by upgrade to the latest Python selenium library:

```
pip install -U selenium
```